# How to show date selection Menu In HTML?

Tags: html

am working on a webPage where i have to accept a date. Have put an image button and onClick of that button i need to show a date selection menu. Can anyone plz tell whether it is possible or not? If possible HOW???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Choose the link on the right "Icon trigger".